# Differentiating argumentless properties in generic inherited interfaces

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface, overloading

Given the case:

```
Public Interface A(Of T)
  Property Objects as List(Of T)
End Interface

Public Interface B
  Inherits A(Of List(Of List))
  Inherits A(Of List(Of Tuple))
End Interface

Public Class C
  Implements B

  Public Sub Retrieve()
    For Each item As Tuple in Objects
      '' Overload resolution failed because no 'Objects' is most specific for these arguments.
    Exit For
  End Sub
End Class
```

The interface `B` has two properties, both named `Objects`, that only differ by their return type. The code satisfies VB.net language conventions up to the point of use. Is there a way to differentiate between the variants of `Objects` at use?

The use case is an object structure that represents a file system, where a folder and a file might be seen as the same kind of entity for some processing, or differentiated and sorted etc. for other kinds of processing. The lists are of an object's children, stored as a list of files, list of folders, or list of objects from which folders and files inherit, so is a combined list (or dictionary) of both files and folders together. I would rather not store multiple lists, but am doing so primarily for efficiency as I don't know of enough fast ways of interrogating a single list to extract/sort the items at time of processing.

I am interested in:

1. Direct syntactic solutions
2. Workarounds
3. Efficient ways of using lists (or dictionaries, enumerables etc.) including Linq, that eliminates any benefit of storing separate containers.

Comment: How does that structure *satisfy VB.net language conventions*? With `Inherits A(Of List(Of List))`? The `B` Interface is not even implemented in `C`, etc.

Comment: You could theoretically cast `Me` to `A(Of List(Of Tuple))` to be able to make the call.  It would probably make more sense to provide explicitly-named members instead of trying to force it through inheritance.